# Problem starting an exe file on remote machine using wmi

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I followed some articles here and managed to start `notepad.exe` on a remote machine.

I am trying to start a third-party software we bought and installed on the remote machine once it restarts, but it's not running the exe..

```
object[] theProcessToRun = { @"C:\Program Files (x86)\xyz\xyz.exe" };

var connection = new ConnectionOptions
{
    Username = "username",
    Password = "password",
    Authority = ""ntlmdomain:.local"",
};
var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\IP\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
scope.Connect();
using (var managementClass = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions()))
{
    managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Sorry, Just edited.

Comment: Notepad is rarely a good example to start working from. It's a remarkably simple program and many things that will trip up more complex programs will not happen to notepad.

Comment: what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I tried your code and it also had an error. So i tried to use the computername instead of the IP. Also I deleted Authority. And then it worked.